# Get data from db and send mails through Mailchimp in PHP

Tags: php, email, sendmail, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am already did this with gmail smtp, with fetch emailid,subject,body and send with phpmailer smtp. Here we can't get exact stats about count of mail openings and deliveries and bounce mails. So we want implement mailchimp api v3. But I cant get any exact resource. How to use mailchimp for this and send individual mails and individual content or mailchimp mergetags.

This is the i am used code for send mails from phpmailer

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from mails_tbale where something condition");
mysql_num_rows($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $mail = new Phpmailer;
    $mail->from = 'xxxxx';
    $mail->Subject = $row["subject"]; 
    $body = $row["content"];
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->Send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are all the rage now-a-days, so you don't have to do any programming yourself. See: https://connect.mailchimp.com However, you would have to commit to a platform, and you loose a lot of control.

If, on the other hand, you want to use pure PHP, you can read http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp and then use one of the many PHP wrappers: https://github.com/pacely/mailchimp-api-v3 or https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api and many more (quality not guaranteed).

Or you could write your own wrapper. The latter two option require more work than using PHP Mailer's SMTP and GMail.

I am using https://postmarkapp.com to do what you want to do with MailChimp, and I am quite happy with it. It has got an officially supported PHP library.

https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-php

I couldn't find that for MailChimp. I'm sure MailChimp will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although not being the exact answer to your question, I would recommend looking at a more api-driven email service provider than MailChimp. I am unsure if you can even send out emails the way you are describing using the MailChimp api since their send-out process are based on your email lists hosted in MailChimp.

One of those being MailChimps [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/), but [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) can also track opens, bounces etc. and provides a good api wrapper for PHP through Composer.